# Android: Creating textview for c++ code

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to create a c++ program app. So how can i show a c++ program code in my xml layout using multiline textview or there is any other suitable way to do that? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NDK : http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/overview.html

> The Android NDK is a toolset that lets you embed components that make
>   use of native code in your Android applications.
>
> Android applications run in the Dalvik virtual machine. The NDK allows
>   you to implement parts of your applications using native-code
>   languages such as C and C++. This can provide benefits to certain
>   classes of applications, in the form of reuse of existing code and in
>   some cases increased speed.